# The following packages have unmet dependencies

Tags: php, ubuntu, gmp, apt-get

I'm trying to install GMP on Ubuntu 14.04:

```
$ sudo apt-get install php5-gmp
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php5-gmp : Depends: php5-common (= 5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.5) but 5.5.17+dfsg-2+deb.sury.org~precise+1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Why is it not letting me install this?

Comment: Googling "Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages." brings me to the helpful http://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages

Comment: sudo apt-get install php5-common php5-gmp

Answer (score 2):

somehow you have installed a special version of php-common (= 5.5.17+dfsg-2+deb.sury.org~precise+1)
try to

```
apt-get remove php5-common
```

and then install again.

Comment: I should've known a reinstall would fix my issue. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

Your installation appears to be broken by `php5-common-5.5.17+dfsg-2+deb.sury.org~precise+1` package installed from some alien repo.

Try to start with:

```
sudo apt-search php5
```

remove everything looking suspicious and then reinstall it from the official repo. I think, simple removal of this alien `common` and reinstalling `gmp` might resolve an issue.